# Is there a clever way to compute the probability of 2 independent events occurring among m events?

Tags: probability

Let's say I have $n$ independant events, $E_1$ to $E_{n} \in E$.

Is there a nice way to compute: $1 \leq i \neq j \leq n, P\left(E_i \land E_j \bigwedge_{k \in E \setminus \{E_i, E_j\}} \neg E_k \right)$

I'm not sure of how to do better than a naive approach where I have an (exponential?) number of probabilities to compute, sadly my program would be extremely slow because of that. Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$\begin{eqnarray}p_i&=&Pr(E_i)\\ 
q_i&=&Pr(not E_i)=1-p_i\\
r_i&=&\frac{p_i}{q_i}\end{eqnarray}$$
Then 
$$\begin{eqnarray}Pr(no E_i) &=& q_1q_2...q_n := Q\\
Pr(one E_i)&=&Q(r_1+r_2+...+r_n)\\
Pr(two E_i)&=&Q(r_1r_2+r_1r_3+...+r_{n-1}r_n)\\
&=&Q\left\{\left[\sum r_i\right]^2-\sum(r_i^2)\right\}/2\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: thanks Michael for the didactic explanation!